# Why Response Header is not shown in Client's shell?

Tags: java, sockets, http, webserver, buffer

I am writing **HTTP WEB SERVER** code.

Till now I implemented **GET, HEAD** method. Now I have to implement OPTIONS method. But this time there is no response received by client's shell. I didn't understand why this is happening. Please help me in that. I am posting my code, please help to detect the error.

**My code**

**Client**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");
          BufferedReader br = null;

          OptionsMethod method = new OptionsMethod("http://10.40.55.240:8080/");

          try {
            int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            if(returnCode == 405 ) {
                System.out.println("The Options method is not implemented by this URI");                
            } else {
                System.out.println("REACH HERE");
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(/*What I put here to get socket InputStream*/);
                String readLine;
                while((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(readLine);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(returnCode);
          } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
                method.releaseConnection();
                if(br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    }   
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                }
         }
    }
}
```

**Server code that respond the client**

```
           else if(methodName.equals("OPTIONS")) {
                System.out.println("GOING TO HANDLE OPTIONS REQUEST");

                printStream.print("HTTP/1.1 " + ServerSettings.HTTP_OK + " OK");
                printStream.write(EOL);
                printStream.print("Date: " + new Date());
                printStream.write(EOL);
                printStream.print("Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD");
                printStream.write(EOL);
                printStream.print("Content-Length: 0");
                printStream.write(EOL);
            }

            inputStream.close();
    printStream.close();
```

Please help me, how can I receive header from server.

What should I put in the  commented portion in the client side, to receive header.

`br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(/*What I put here to get socket InputStream*/);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of above question, It is as follows:-

As there is no `Response Body` for `Options Method`. So, here server respond only Header, and it can be shown on client shell is by using following statements:-

```
int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
if(returnCode == 405 ) {
        System.out.println("The Options method is not implemented by this URI");
} else {
        Header[] header = method.getResponseHeaders();
        for(int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(header[i].getName() + ": " + header[i].getValue());
        }
}
```

If for other methods , if there is any response body also, than we can use the below code,

```
try {
    int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    if(returnCode == 405 ) {
        System.out.println("The XXX method is not implemented by this URI");
    } else {
        Header[] header = method.getResponseHeaders();
        for(int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(header[i].getName() + ": " + header[i].getValue());
        }
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        String readLine;
        while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
        System.out.println("close method");
        method.releaseConnection();
        try {
        br.close();
        } 
        catch(IOException ioe) {}
 }
```